# Login access not working in yii2

Tags: yii2

Im using yii2 for my project. I need to use two different tables for login (Login page is same). I have two models **Admin** and **User**. And i have one **LoginFrom** for login.

I can login properly but the problem is after logged in i cannot get whether the admin is logged in or the user is logged in.

I have set it in config file (web.php) like below:

```
'admin' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Admin',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'authTimeout' => 1200, // in Seconds. 1200 seconds means 20 mins
    ],
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 1200
    ],
```

So im getting logged in user details by using below method:

```
\Yii::$app->admin->identity;
\Yii::$app->user->identity;
```

My problem is if im logged in as admin i can get user values also by using this : **\Yii::$app->user->identity;** or if im logged in as user i can get admin values by using this : **\Yii::$app->admin->identity;**.

My LoginForm.php is :

```
<?php
 namespace app\models;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Model;

 class LoginForm extends Model
 {
   public $username;
   public $password;
   public $rememberMe = true;

   private $_user = false;

   public function rules()
   {
      return [
        // username and password are both required
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        // rememberMe must be a boolean value
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
      ];
    }

    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
       if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
          $user = $this->getUser();

          if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
              $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
          }
       }
     }

     public function login()
     {
         if ($this->validate()) {
            if(!empty($this->getUser()['phone_number'])) {
                return Yii::$app->admin->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
            } else {
                return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
            }
         }
         return false;
      }

      public function getUser()
      {
         if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);

            if(!$this->_user) {
                $this->_user = Admin::findByUsername($this->username);
             }
          }

          return $this->_user;
       }
    }
```

I cant find the problem and if i logged in identity creating for both the users so i could'nt write access rules in particular controller to allow admin only to access the controller.Please help me :(

Comment: Why do you need two identities? Why not just use RBAC and define role Admin?
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization

Comment: i would agree with @Aivar here you should use RBAC and define roles rather than creating 2 separate identities or tables.

Comment: I have to use two tables that's why @Aivar

Comment: There is no way to use two tables for login in yii2 :(

Comment: Problem is i should'nt change my table structure

Comment: @Smarty At the moment i cannot understand why you need separate tables and identities. You should not need them. If you need extra data you can use "admin" table with related user.id. Then you can ask from user model those fields via relations.

Comment: @Smarty If you want just to know user is "admin" then you can just check what class ise used for identity. example
if (\Yii::$app->admin->identity instanceof \app\models\Admin)
But i think i would go with one identity only and what quaranties that you do not have same username in both tables? Easier to use one table only for base identity.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments I think you should just create a unifying table for the two identities where they both get their IDs from. Then make that the identity class. The reason you are able to see the details in both identity classes is that they have the same ID.